# virtual audio recorder/playback in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, virtual, avaudiorecorder, wifi-direct

Is there a way to achieve inter-app audio in android.
Directly transmits audio streams from one device to another device using wifi-direct.

Are there any native (NDK) API's which support virtual mic kind of in android, i.e an api which stores(record) audio and any third party android app can playback the recorded audio.

Thanks in advance for any help.